# Running .sql file in Android

Tags: android, mysql, database-connection

Hello I have a mysql file and I want to create a local database in my android application and show the tables in my app.
Is there any way to run this .sql file in android ?

Comment: Did you mean sql script for **sqlite**?

Comment: this is the file i want to work on it
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lE1m8tzCfkGnLaaSfWCSadbLeFcRyDER

Comment: You've shown a mysql script. Remove the following statements and it should be the same as a sqlite script.
`-- drop database university;
create database University;
use University;

commit;
`

After that, check these links: 
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)